# Why can't I open a PDF file with ImageMagickNet?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick.net

Here is the code in question:

```
MagickNet.InitializeMagick();
ImageMagickNET.Image image = new ImageMagickNET.Image(@"C:\temp.pdf");
image.Quality = 100;
image.CompressType = ImageMagickNET.CompressionType.LosslessJPEGCompression;
image.Write(@"C:\temp.jpg");
```

I'm fairly certain this code should work, but I get the exceptionally informative exception of: `External component has thrown an exception.`

This exception is thrown on the line: `ImageMagickNET.Image image = new ImageMagickNET.Image(@"C:\temp.pdf");`

InnerException: null

StackTrace:

```
   at Magick.Image.{ctor}(Image* , basic_string<char\,std::char_traits<char>\,std::allocator<char> >* )
   at ImageMagickNET.Image..ctor(String imageSpec)
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.ReadQRCode(String doc) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs:line 126
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.seperatePDFsInOrder(String fileName) in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs:line 109
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.Designer.cs:line 44
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1..ctor() in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs:line 16
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.Program.Main() in C:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\Program.cs:line 20
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Anyone have any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Any inner exceptions? Stack trace?

Comment: @Oded Sorry about that. Added both to original post.

Comment: Why are you trying to load a PDF file into an image manipulation library? Does the file actually exist in that location?

Comment: @Oded I am trying to convert a pdf to a jpg. This code was taken from an example that claimed to do the job. The file does exist in that location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to declare your `image = new` as a ***.pdf** file in your 2nd quoted line. Better try it with `c:\tmp.jpg`. Or even better `c:\temp\tmp.jpg`...

ImageMagick applies its *'I want to parse this file as a PDF'*-mode if it sees the suffix *.pdf. (It applies its magic file type discovery routines only if the filename doesn't have a suffix.)

Also the user that is running the code possibly cannot write the file `c:\tmp.jpg`. There could be two reasons:

1. c:\ as a directory is not writeable for this user.
2. the file already exists, and can't be overwritten by this user (it may belong to another user).

Lastly, **be aware that ImageMagick's capability to process PDFs as input relies on an external 'delegate':** it can't do that job itself, it requires a Ghostscript installation on the same host to call it and let it do the job...

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. When I return to work on Monday I will apply it to my issue. You seem to be very knowledgeable about this issue and I was wondering if you could lend me some quick advice. All I am trying to do is convert several 1 page PDFS to images. I need to process the images, but don't even care about saving them. Am I going about this the correct way, or would you suggest a different solution? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, the running code is not editing a file in c:\. I just edited the path for this question.

Comment: So **what** are you trying to do with those images if they are not saved? What kind of further processing? Have you considered to do that in a pipeline?

Comment: I am scanning them for QR codes. The QR decoding library that I am supposed to use only accepts images. I just need to read the QR codes then name the PDFs based on the info encoded in them.

Comment: So you could work with a pipe or FIFO to get the image from (instead of a file handle)?

Comment: I was able to try out your solution this morning. I was having an issue with GhostScript. Restarting my comp fixed the issue and the program is now working as desired. Thank you again for your responses!